# Symfony using external parameters in assert and routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes, assert

We are working on a big Symfony2 project which should be as portable and configurable as possible.
As security is super important in our project we use many validation and so on.
For example we use assert in the entity and also check requirements in routing. 
For example in the entity:

> - @Assert\Range(
>
>   - min = 1,
>   - max = 3,
>   - minMessage = "common.moderation.status.range_min",
>   - maxMessage = "common.moderation.status.range_max"
>   - )
>
> and in routing:  requirements:
>           status: "[1-3]"

We would like to find a way to store these range values separately and use them in entities and routes. At the moment these (and other consts) statuses are stored in the entity as constants but as the project grows we will need more and more constants and fields and routes with validation for these values which will cause many duplications like this. Also if one of our customers want to change the range can cause headaches. 
Is it possible to not manually rewrite all the necessary asserts and route requirements but only an external parameter? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should [create a custom Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).